# If any contains do X if not do Y

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to work out the proper formula for this.
If any of these cells (A2, B4, C6, etc) contain a value > 0, return -1. If not then do this IF statement.

Essentially an IF ELSE statement, but with multiple individual cell checks instead of an all or nothing cell check.

Comment: There is not enough information given to offer a solution. Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet; and we don't know your data, data types, layout or end goal unless you share them with us.

Comment: Just for instance, your post supplies as an example `A2, B4, C6...` These follow a pattern. And answering that question would start from a different supposition than if your actual cells are in some other pattern, or if they are completely random. Likewise, would you want a return of -1 or [other] returned/done ONCE, in one cell; or would you need a return for EACH/ANY of the listed cells returned somewhere? And if the latter, where? As you can see, without more information, ranges, etc., your explanation is just "floating in space."

Comment: you are referring to `nested if` statements. [This reference](https://launchpad.scsrockets.org/how-to-get-started-with-nested-if-statements-in-google-sheets/) and [this one](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-use-if-and-nested-if-in-google-sheets/) gets you started. After reading them, [edit] your question if you have issues with examples which are troubling you. Help the community to help you!

Comment: Ah apologies! I see how that could be vague. I have a series of cells with numbers in them. In a different cell I need a formula that says If any of these 6 cells have a number >0 in them the new cell shows -1. If they do not have any numbers >0 than complete this formula: =IF(F4>=$V$1, IF(D4="",-1,0),1).  So essentially I need an IF ANY that runs into an IF. I'm reading your reference on nested IFs now. Thank you!

Comment: It seems from the references I will need to nest an IF statement per reference cell and one additional for the else formula. Unless I'm missing a step and I will need to nest a statement for each reference cell as well as one for each cell's else

Comment: Again, Patrick, we can't see what you see, and we don't know what you know. I can "feel" that you believe what you're saying makes perfect sense. But I can only assure you that this is only because you are starting with all the pieces. It is best to SHOW us all the pieces and then SHOW us the end result (manually entered) that you want. To that end, I encourage you to share a link to a sample spreadsheet containing enough realistic data to illustrate the problem as well as that manually-typed solution, where you'd like those results to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Please see all of the comments to your original post.

However, I will *attempt* to answer your question based on the few pieces you've given paired with my own imagination filling in the gaps. At least you may come away with a nudge in the right direction.

Also understand that there are any number of ways to get the same result. There is no "one function that does that" (whatever "that" may be).

For your six noncontiguous cells that you want to check for a positive value, I'll just assume they are as follows (since you haven't provided them for us): `A2`, `B4`, `C6`, `D8`, `E3`, `F5`.

This formula might produce the results you are after:

`=IF(NOT(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT("~"&JOIN("~",A2,B4,C6,D8,E3,F5)&"~","~[\d,\.]+~"))),-1,IF(F4>=$V$1,IF(D4="",-1,0),1))`

This would produce the same result as above:

`=IF(IFERROR(A2*1>0)+IFERROR(B4*1>0)+IFERROR(C6*1>0)+IFERROR(D8*1>0)+IFERROR(E3*1>0)+IFERROR(F5*1>0),-1,IF(F4>=$V$1,IF(D4="",-1,0),1))`

This would also produce the same result:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(SUM(N(IFERROR({A2,B4,C6,D8,E3,F5}*1)>0)),-1,IF(F4>=$V$1,IF(D4="",-1,0),1)))`

This would also produce the same result:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(NOT(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(TRUE,IFERROR({A2,B4,C6,D8,E3,F5}*1>0),1,FALSE))),-1,IF(F4>=$V$1,IF(D4="",-1,0),1)))`

As I say, there are many ways to tackle something.

In addition, all of the formulas above are longer than they may have needed to be, because we don't know the nature of the possible input values for the first six noncontiguous cells. Without that information, I had to write the formulas as if they *could contain **anything*** (i.e., null, numbers, strings, Boolean values). If we'd had all the information in front of us, and it were clear that those cells would only ever hold null or a legitimate number, I would have written the formulas differently, because they wouldn't have needed all the `IFERROR` checks.

The starting point must always be fully understanding the data and the end goal. If the above formulas work for you, then we lucked out this time. In that case, I'll leave it to you to choose the formula that you feel you can best unravel and seek to understand it.

If not, per all of the comments, please ***show*** us the data, layout and end goal rather than merely trying to explain it.